# Making my own photo-mosaic app with Qt using C++

Tags: c++, qt, image-processing, qt-creator, genetic-algorithm

This is the output of what I have done till now:
[image]

Although this shows only black and white images, the code works for color images too. The code basically populates the larger image using smaller images from a small database.
So this is where I am stuck, rather clueless.
[How can I get an effect like this one.](http://www.absolutearts.com/cgi-bin/portfolio/art/your-art.cgi?login=jonlijo&title=Princess_Diana_Collage-1382910250t.jpg) or [this one](http://www.engadget.com/2004/10/19/how-to-make-your-own-photo-mosaics/).
Qn1 : I need to take another input(large) image*(One for which the effect is to be seen)* and merge them, but how?
Qn2 : How can I evaluate the goodness of the photo-mosaic? I have a genetic algorithm written for this but am unable to fix the fitness function,(mutation and crossover work perfectly).

This is what I could think of(for Qn1):
1. Take alternate pixels of the image shown above and the image for which the mosaic has to be made.
2. Take average of the pixel values of the above and input image for which the mosaic has to be made.
But have no clue to evaluate the goodness.

Comment: This is a nice challenge: who can give an answer in the least amount of lines of code. It would really show the power of Qt, as I believe the complete project can be quite tiny. Surely under 200 lines (the whole thing)!

Comment: @KubaOber: Could you give some hints/algorithm for solving it.. I could try coding it of my own. Under 200 lines sounds amazing!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below is a self contained sketch. The mosaicing algorithm is mid-way through the algorithms implemented in [an excellent reference](http://blog.wolfram.com/2008/05/02/making-photo-mosaics/). It works well enough for two hours of work, I think. I tried for the code to be reasonably correct, with two caveats, left, as they say, as an exercise to the reader.

1. I'm not tracking the worker threads - if you try to exit the application while workers are active, it is expected to crash on exit. This is not nice, but otherwise benign and doesn't affect the overall functionality. There may be a few corrupt images left on disk, but those should be ignored when reloading.
2. There is no scaling of the image displayed in the label. The window will resize to the image size.

The tile image database can be filled with random images from imgur, you can also fill it with your own images by storing them on disk yourself. It's located in a standard application data path suffixed by `/so-photomosaic/image`. The fetched images are added there. Upon startup, the image database is repopulated from disk in the background - that's how your own tile images would be loaded. In fact, all of image processing is done in non-GUI threads. On a rather unassuming 5 year old Core 2 OS X system, disk image loading proceeds at about 5000 images/s. The images requested from imgur are their small size, or 90x90.

The tile matching is done with a 4x4 subdivision grid (`divs` parameter to `calcPropsFor`). The images are downsampled to a 4x4 mosaic, and the RGB color values of consecutive pixels in that grid are stored in `Props` vectors. The squared sums of differences of elements of those vectors are the measure of fit. For each tile to be replaced, the images are sorted according to their fit, and one of the best ones are picked up at random. The randomness parameter is a power-of-to of the sample size from which the image is randomly selected.

It uses Qt 5 and C++11. Length: 300 lines, out of which 64 are the random image source, 25 are the disk image database, and 88 are actually to do with mosaics. The image processing code would probably look and perform better if OpenCV or Eigen was used instead of valarray/QImage, but oh well.

Also, all of this would be probably 50 lines in Mathematica :)

[image: screenshot]

```
# main.pro
# Make sure to re-run quake once this is set.
TEMPLATE = app
QT += widgets network concurrent
CONFIG += c++11
SOURCES += main.cpp
TARGET = photomosaic
```

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QSlider>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QCheckBox>
#include <QBoxLayout>
#include <QFileDialog>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QRegularExpression>
#include <QImage>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QColor>
#include <QAtomicInt>
#include <QMutex>
#include <QtConcurrent>
#include <QStandardPaths>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <valarray>

/// Provides random images. There may be more than one response per request.
class RandomImageSource : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  int m_parallelism;
  bool m_auto;
  QNetworkAccessManager m_mgr;
  QSet<QNetworkReply*> m_replies;
  QList<QUrl> m_deferred;
  QRegularExpression m_imgTagRE, m_imgUrlRE;
  QUrl m_randomGallery;
  void get(const QUrl & url) {
    if (m_replies.count() < m_parallelism) {
      QNetworkRequest req(url);
      req.setAttribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpPipeliningAllowedAttribute, true);
      m_replies.insert(m_mgr.get(req));
    } else
      m_deferred << url;
  }
  void finishReply(QNetworkReply * reply) {
    m_replies.remove(reply);
    if (reply) reply->deleteLater();
    if (! m_deferred.isEmpty()) get(m_deferred.takeLast());
    while (m_deferred.isEmpty() && m_auto) get(m_randomGallery);
  }
  Q_SLOT void rsp(QNetworkReply * reply) {
    auto loc = reply->header(QNetworkRequest::LocationHeader);
    if (loc.isValid()) {
      get(loc.toUrl()); // redirect
    } else {
      auto ct = reply->header(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader).toString();
      if (ct.startsWith("text/html"))
        foreach (QUrl url, parseImageUrls(reply->readAll()))
          get(url);
      else if (ct.startsWith("image")) {
        auto img = QImage::fromData(reply->readAll());
        img.setText("filename", m_imgUrlRE.match(reply->url().toString()).captured(1));
        if (!img.isNull()) emit rspImage(img);
      }
    }
    finishReply(reply);
  }
  QList<QUrl> parseImageUrls(const QByteArray & html) {
    QList<QUrl> urls;
    auto it = m_imgTagRE.globalMatch(QString::fromUtf8(html));
    while (it.hasNext()) { auto match = it.next(); // get small images
      urls << QUrl("http:" + match.captured(1) + "s" + match.captured(2)); }
    return urls;
  }
public:
  RandomImageSource(QObject * parent = 0) : QObject (parent),
    m_parallelism(20), m_auto(false),
    m_imgTagRE("<img src=\"(//i\\.imgur\\.com/[^.]+)(\\.[^\"]+)\""),
    m_imgUrlRE("http://i\\.imgur\\.com/(.+)$"),
    m_randomGallery("http://imgur.com/gallery/random")
  {
    connect(&m_mgr, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), SLOT(rsp(QNetworkReply*)));
  }
  Q_SLOT void reqImages(int count) {
    while (count--) get(m_randomGallery);
  }
  Q_SIGNAL void rspImage(const QImage &);
  bool automatic() const { return m_auto; }
  Q_SLOT void setAutomatic(bool a) { if ((m_auto = a)) finishReply(0); }
  int parallelism() const { return m_parallelism; }
  Q_SLOT void setParallelism(int p) { m_parallelism = p; if (m_auto) finishReply(0); }
};

/// Stores images on disk, and loads them in the background.
class ImageStorage : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  QString const m_path;
public:
  ImageStorage() :
    m_path(QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::DataLocation)
           + "/images/")
  { QDir().mkpath(m_path); }
  Q_SLOT void addImage(const QImage & img) {
    QString path = img.text("filename");
    if (path.isEmpty()) return;
    path.prepend(m_path);
    QtConcurrent::run([img, path]{ img.save(path); });
  }
  Q_SLOT void retrieveAll() {
    QString const path = m_path;
    QtConcurrent::run([this, path] {
      QStringList const images = QDir(path).entryList(QDir::Files);
      foreach (QString image, images) QtConcurrent::run([this, image, path] {
        QImage img; if (img.load(path + image)) emit retrieved(img);
      });
    });
  }
  Q_SIGNAL void retrieved(const QImage &);
};

/// A memory database of images. Finds best match to a given image.
class ImageDatabase : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  typedef std::valarray<qreal> Props;
  typedef QPair<QImage, Props> ImageProps;
  QMutex mutable m_mutex;
  QList<ImageProps> m_images;
  static void inline addProps(Props & p, int i, QRgb rgb) {
    QColor const c = QColor::fromRgb(rgb);
    p[i+0] += c.redF(); p[i+1] += c.greenF(); p[i+2] += c.blueF();
  }
  static Props calcPropsFor(const QImage & img, int divs = 4) {
    Props props(0.0, 3 * divs * divs);
    std::valarray<int> counts(0, divs * divs);
    QSize div = img.size() / divs;
    for (int y = 0; y < img.height(); ++y)
      for (int x = 0; x < img.width(); ++x) {
        int slice = x/div.width() + (y*divs/div.height());
        if (slice >= divs*divs) continue;
        addProps(props, slice*3, img.pixel(x, y));
        counts[slice] ++;
      }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < props.size(); ++i) props[i] /= counts[i/3];
    return props;
  }
public:
  Q_SIGNAL void newImageCount(int);
  Q_SLOT void addImage(const QImage & img) {
    QtConcurrent::run([this, img]{
      Props props = calcPropsFor(img);
      QMutexLocker lock(&m_mutex);
      m_images << qMakePair(img, props);
      int count = m_images.count();
      lock.unlock();
      emit newImageCount(count);
    });
  }
  ImageProps bestMatchFor(const QImage & img, int randLog2) const {
    QMutexLocker lock(&m_mutex);
    QList<ImageProps> const images = m_images;
    lock.unlock();
    Props const props = calcPropsFor(img);
    typedef QPair<qreal, const ImageProps *> Match;
    QList<Match> matches; matches.reserve(images.size());
    std::transform(images.begin(), images.end(), std::back_inserter(matches),
                   [props](const ImageProps & prop){
      return qMakePair(pow(props - prop.second, 2).sum(), &prop);
    });
    std::sort(matches.begin(), matches.end(),
              [](Match a, Match b) { return b.first < a.first; });
    randLog2 = 1<<randLog2;
    return *(matches.end()-randLog2+qrand()%randLog2)->second;
  }
};

QImage getMosaic(QImage img, const ImageDatabase & db, int size, int randLog2)
{
  QPainter p(&img);
  for (int y = 0; y < img.height(); y += size)
    for (int x = 0; x < img.width(); x += size) {
      QImage r = db.bestMatchFor(img.copy(x, y, size, size), randLog2).first
          .scaled(size, size, Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation);
      p.drawImage(x, y, r);
    }
  return img;
}

class MosaicGenerator : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  QPointer<ImageDatabase> m_db;
  int m_size, m_randLog2;
  QAtomicInt m_busy;
  QImage m_image;
  void update() {
    if (m_image.isNull() || m_busy.fetchAndAddOrdered(1)) return;
    QImage image = m_image;
    QtConcurrent::run([this, image]{ while (true) {
        emit hasMosaic(getMosaic(image, *m_db, m_size, m_randLog2));
        if (m_busy.testAndSetOrdered(1, 0)) return;
        m_busy.fetchAndStoreOrdered(1);
      }});
  }
public:
  MosaicGenerator(ImageDatabase * db) : m_db(db), m_size(16), m_randLog2(0) {}
  Q_SLOT void setImage(const QImage & img) { m_image = img; update(); }
  Q_SLOT void setSize(int s) { m_size = s; update(); }
  Q_SLOT void setRandLog2(int r) { m_randLog2 = r; update(); }
  Q_SIGNAL void hasMosaic(const QImage &);
};

class Window : public QWidget {
  Q_OBJECT
  bool m_showSource;
  QImage m_source, m_mosaic;
  QBoxLayout m_layout;
  QSlider m_parallelism, m_cellSize, m_randomness;
  QLabel m_imgCount, m_parCount, m_image;
  QPushButton m_add, m_load, m_toggle;
  MosaicGenerator m_gen;
  Q_SIGNAL void newSource(const QImage &);
  void updateImage() {
    const QImage & img = m_showSource ? m_source : m_mosaic;
    m_image.setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img));
  }
public:
  Window(ImageDatabase * db, QWidget * parent = 0) : QWidget(parent),
    m_showSource(true), m_layout(QBoxLayout::TopToBottom, this),
    m_parallelism(Qt::Horizontal), m_cellSize(Qt::Horizontal),
    m_randomness(Qt::Horizontal), m_add("Fetch Images"),
    m_load("Open for Mosaic"), m_toggle("Toggle Mosaic"), m_gen(db)
  {
    QBoxLayout * row = new QBoxLayout(QBoxLayout::LeftToRight);
    row->addWidget(new QLabel("Images in DB:"));
    row->addWidget(&m_imgCount);
    row->addWidget(new QLabel("Fetch parallelism:"));
    row->addWidget(&m_parallelism);
    row->addWidget(&m_parCount);
    row->addWidget(&m_add);
    m_parallelism.setRange(1, 100);
    m_layout.addLayout(row);
    m_layout.addWidget(&m_image);
    row = new QBoxLayout(QBoxLayout::LeftToRight);
    row->addWidget(new QLabel("Cell Size:"));
    row->addWidget(&m_cellSize);
    row->addWidget(new QLabel("Randomness:"));
    row->addWidget(&m_randomness);
    m_cellSize.setRange(4, 64); m_cellSize.setTracking(false);
    m_randomness.setRange(0,6); m_randomness.setTracking(false);
    m_layout.addLayout(row);
    row = new QBoxLayout(QBoxLayout::LeftToRight);
    row->addWidget(&m_load);
    row->addWidget(&m_toggle);
    m_layout.addLayout(row);
    m_add.setCheckable(true);
    m_parCount.connect(&m_parallelism, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), SLOT(setNum(int)));
    connect(&m_add, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), SIGNAL(reqAutoFetch(bool)));
    connect(&m_parallelism, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), SIGNAL(reqParallelism(int)));
    m_gen.connect(&m_cellSize, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), SLOT(setSize(int)));
    m_gen.connect(&m_randomness, SIGNAL(valueChanged(int)), SLOT(setRandLog2(int)));
    m_parallelism.setValue(20);
    m_cellSize.setValue(16);
    m_randomness.setValue(4);
    connect(&m_load, &QPushButton::clicked, [this]{
      QString file = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this);
      QtConcurrent::run([this, file]{
        QImage img; if (!img.load(file)) return;
        emit newSource(img);
      });
    });
    connect(this, &Window::newSource, [this](const QImage &img){
      m_source = m_mosaic = img; updateImage(); m_gen.setImage(m_source);
    });
    connect(&m_gen, &MosaicGenerator::hasMosaic, [this](const QImage &img){
      m_mosaic = img; updateImage();
    });
    connect(&m_toggle, &QPushButton::clicked, [this]{
      m_showSource = !m_showSource; updateImage();
    });
  }
  Q_SLOT void setImageCount(int n) { m_imgCount.setNum(n); }
  Q_SIGNAL void reqAutoFetch(bool);
  Q_SIGNAL void reqParallelism(int);
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  a.setOrganizationDomain("stackoverflow.com");
  a.setApplicationName("so-photomosaic");
  RandomImageSource src;
  ImageDatabase db;
  ImageStorage stg;
  Window ui(&db);
  db.connect(&src, SIGNAL(rspImage(QImage)), SLOT(addImage(QImage)));
  stg.connect(&src, SIGNAL(rspImage(QImage)), SLOT(addImage(QImage)));
  db.connect(&stg, SIGNAL(retrieved(QImage)), SLOT(addImage(QImage)));
  ui.connect(&db, SIGNAL(newImageCount(int)), SLOT(setImageCount(int)));
  src.connect(&ui, SIGNAL(reqAutoFetch(bool)), SLOT(setAutomatic(bool)));
  src.connect(&ui, SIGNAL(reqParallelism(int)), SLOT(setParallelism(int)));
  stg.retrieveAll();
  ui.show();
  return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: @SahilSareen To use this project you need *exactly* two files. The .pro file and the main.cpp file. There *is no* MainWindow anything. You're making life very complicated for yourself by assuming stuff that's not there. It works. Copy-paste those two files from this answer into a fresh folder, open it up in Qt Creator, select the Qt version, and hit Ctrl-R (or Cmd-R). That's literally it. I've just tried.

Comment: @SahilSareen To give you the idea about number of needed images: 5000 is a bit on the low side. If you set the fetch parallelism low (say to 5), you should be able to run it for a couple minutes to get about 20,000 pictures. That's when it gets really good. 50,000 pictures is even better, but you need a 64 bit system for that, and it'll gobble up a few gigabytes of RAM. It could be made to run with  the tiles on-disk only consuming much less RAM, so maybe I'd do that little change later.