# Is this a decent structure for a multithreaded videocoacher program?

Tags: multithreading, qt, opencv, structure

Hi I’m currently working on a project for a videocoacher program for recording and replaying video, as well as showing delayed real-time video, and tracking placement via color.

The software is running on linux , on a 4 core odroid, and initially I started to make it multi threaded with threads implemented as a part of each new class. Each of these threads taking care of their own gui elements.

I’ve later found out that I need to show all gui elements/video in the main/gui thread. Earlier I’ve used opencv and boost. But it seems like using the Qt might be a better idea since some of the code already depends on the QT library. I am currently a novice at programming, and not very familiar with either opencv, qt, or threading.

**My question is:
 Is this relatively sound as a structure for the program, or is there something inherently wrong with how I am planning to do it now?**

**Main/GUI Thread**

- will show all visual & video content
- will start a thread for **ButtonControl** object

**ButtonControl**

- will handle all button input, controlling what happens in the program
- depending on what buttons are pressed will start and end threads
  like:
- **StoreToFile** object ( starts storing video to a file, while sending a
  video stream to **GUI thread** to show what it is storing in real-time)
- **ReadFromFile** object ( reads the file currently stored and sends data
  to display it in **GUI thread**
- **DelayedVideoStream** object (stores video to buffer, and shows a
  continuous delayed view of what happened 5seconds in the past)
- **ColorTracking** object (tracks where a color placement is in the image
  )

Kind regards, and thank you for taking the time to look at my question.

**TLDR - is a structure where threads are implemented as classes and the image data is sent back to the gui/main thread a decent way to do a multithreaded program ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance-wise, the best approach is not to deal with threads directly at all, but use `QtConcurrent::run`. It is safe to paint `QImages` that are simply passed via signals to a GUI object to display. I wrote [a complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22674903/1329652) demonstrating that approach. It leads to some very concise and easy-to-understand code thanks to related code being adjacent.

If you do want to use explicit threads, it will be much easier not to derive from `QThread`, but to simply move various worker objects  into their threads, and have them communicate via signals and slots. I have [a complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21253353/1329652) for that approach as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, as well as the examples. I'm very new to both multithreading, QT and opencv.I think I will go with using QTConcurrent like you suggested since as you say  that is the easiest to understand.