# Image Sequence Player using QT

Tags: c++, image, qt, video, sequence

Hy!

There are a lot of articles around but I think I need a hint where to start.
I have a sequence of rendered images which I created with Maya. I would now like to show a video using QT5.5 / C++.

Any ideas which options are around?

- Converting the images to a video (e.g. ffmpeg)?
- Creating a .GIF and using QVideo?
- Using the QT Multimedia functionalities but with the images instead of a video?

Can anyone please share their experiences?

Comment: It depends on your final delivery platform.

Comment: Very broad question with lots of "correct" answers. But I would just convert the sequence to a video if that is how it's supposed to be shown.

Comment: I am implementing a desktop application. Yes, converting it to a video is straightforward. I renderer an animation from three viewpoints, and I would like to switch between the animations (i.e. videos) in real-time. So I am wondering if I run into problems when loading the videos. Any of course, I need three videos for one animation (or even more) ...

Comment: I already implemented a video player, but can't find goof tutorials about how to show the "video" using only the images... And links?

Comment: Converting to video is the best to my mind. Loading of separate image would take more resources. GIF can use only 256 colors.

Comment: Ok, that's a good point. Does QT provide some Classes to convert images to a video? Otherwise I think ffmpeg is fine ...

Comment: You wrote _I would like to switch between the animations (i.e. videos) in real-time._  Do you want to show render in real time?

Comment: Lets say I have an animation rendered from left and right - 2 images stacks with 100 images each. My plan is to create two videos. Now I would like to play the first video, and if the user pushes a button (frame 22), the second video should start (frame 23). etc ...

Comment: First my idea is to create two instances of `QMediaPlayer` and open these video files using two players. When user wants to switch view just stop first player, call [`QMediaPlayer::setPosition()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#position-prop) on second player and start it ([`QMediaPlayer::play()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplayer.html#play)). At the beginning open video files in player. I think it will work quick enough.

Comment: Ok that sounds good. Do you see any problem in using a "list" or array of such QMediaPlayer instances? One other idea I had is to use a simple QLabel and show the pixmap. Of cours with a delay between the frames. Anyway, video sounds good for me...

Answer (score 0):

You can be keeping a certain number of images pre-loaded asynchronously, and asynchronously convert them to a screen-compatible image format and size. Then the main thread can blit them to the window - that should be pretty fast.

You don't need any video functionality for that. Only `QtConcurrent::run` to load and convert the images asynchronously, and a timer to show them in the main (gui) thread.

Comment: Ok I think I will try also your idea. What do you mean with "QtConcurrent::run to load and convert the images asynchronously"?

Comment: @PatrickWolf Like in [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22674903/1329652) (the code isn't perfect, but shows the technique).